# Left Joins returns duplicate values

Tags: mysql

The result I receive:

```
id   sku           name                                                              GROUP_CONCAT(quantity_received)                                                                                                            GROUP_CONCAT(item_cost)                                      
4   00004   Antibacterial Wipes     50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309,50,14,25,309    3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49,3.29,3.29,3.29,3.49
```

The result I want:

```
id   sku            name        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quantity_received)    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_cost)
4   00004   Antibacterial Wipes             50,14,25,309                            3.29,3.49
```

The way I resolved this issue was placing DISTINCT in the quantity_recieved select. The problem is that if the quantity has two values that are the same such as 50, 50, 14, 25. The result will be 50, 14, 25. I just want to get rid of the repeating numbers and only get the values once.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `product`.`id`,`product`.`sku`,`product`.`name`,
    case when coalesce(stock1.`quantity`, '') = '' 
        then '0' 
        else stock1.`quantity` 
    end as qty_warehouse,
    case when coalesce(sum(distinct stock2.`quantity`), '') = '' 
        then '0' 
        else sum(distinct stock2.`quantity`) 
    end as qty_events,
    case when coalesce(stock1.`quantity`, '') = '' 
        then '0' 
        else stock1.`quantity` 
    end + 
    case when coalesce(sum(distinct stock2.`quantity`), '') = '' 
        then '0' 
        else sum(distinct stock2.`quantity`) 
    end as qty_total
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quantity_received) ,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_cost)
FROM (`product`)
LEFT JOIN`shipping_event` 
    ON `shipping_event`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `product_stock` as stock1 
    ON `product`.`id` = `stock1`.`product_id` and `stock1`.`location_id` = 112 
LEFT JOIN `product_stock` as stock2 
    ON `product`.`id` = `stock2`.`product_id` and `stock2`.`location_id` != 112  
LEFT JOIN `shipping_list` 
    ON `shipping_event`.`shipping_list_id` = `shipping_list`.`id` 
WHERE `shipping_list`.`type` = 'incoming' 
    AND `shipping_event`.`end_date` > '2004-01-01 01:01:01' 
GROUP BY `product`.`id` 
ORDER BY `sku` asc LIMIT 20
```

I am using group concat just to display the result in this case. I actually sum the quantity_received and then multiple them by the item cost.

Comment: have you tried to use DISTINCT in your select part?

Comment: Yes, but like I explained that with DISTINCT , if the quantity_received has two values that are the same such as 50, 50, 14, 25. The result will be 50, 14, 25. In the example I need to get the four distinct values before they repeat.

Comment: Which table do the `quantity_received` and `item_cost` come from?

Comment: They both come from shipping_event

Comment: To confirm your content, you have LEFT JOIN to Shipping event and then Shipping list tables.  However, the WHERE clause includes both which results in an INNER JOIN -- thus REQUIRING only those entries found in shipping event and shipping list.  Is that what was intended, or ALL products REGARDLESS of being shipped event/list records found.  They are two very different query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a subquery with a `GROUP BY` and then `JOIN` to the `product` table.

The same logic can be applied to the other joined tables as well. If you do that, you can skip the `GROUP BY product.id`:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.sku
     , p.name
     , COALESCE(stock1.quantity, 0)                  --- minor improvements on
         AS qty_warehouse                            --- the long CASE clauses
     , COALESCE(SUM(DISTINCT stock2.quantity), 0) 
         AS qty_events
     , COALESCE(stock1.quantity, 0) + COALESCE(SUM(DISTINCT stock2.quantity), 0)
         AS qty_total
     , grp.all_quantities_received
     , grp.all_item_costs
FROM product AS p
  LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT product_id
             , GROUP_CONCAT(se.quantity_received) AS all_quantities_received
             , GROUP_CONCAT(se.item_cost)         AS all_item_costs
        FROM shipping_event AS se
          LEFT JOIN shipping_list AS sl
            ON  se.shipping_list_id = sl.id 
        WHERE sl.type = 'incoming' 
          AND se.end_date > '2004-01-01 01:01:01' 
        GROUP BY se.product_id
      ) AS grp
    ON  grp.product_id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN `product_stock` AS stock1 
    ON  p.id = stock1.product_id 
    AND stock1.location_id = 112 
  LEFT JOIN product_stock AS stock2 
    ON  p.id = stock2.product_id 
    AND stock2.location_id <> 112  
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY sku ASC
LIMIT 20
```